# Spring Boot JPA CrudRepository selective update - only some properties

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

While using Hibernate with Spring Boot JPA, I noticed that when trying to implement an update method in a repository artifact that extends Spring's CrudRepository interface, that the entire entity object to be updated must be passed in to such an update method. Just intuitively that seemed wasteful and I wanted to know what is a clean way to get Spring Data/JPA to assume that only those values passed in need updating and to leave those not passed in untouched.

This is the service method as it stands right now,

```
   public void updateCustomer(Long id, Customer customer) throws Exception {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

Comment: *Premature optimization is the root of all evil*. Why do you think it is wasteful... How are you going to determine which fields change (let me guess, get the full object, compare field by field and construct a query) the time lost with trying to figure out what has changed is possible larger then updating all fields not to mention the added complexity. If you want selective updates hibernate already has support for that to determine it by itself (but as mentioned use selectively). Not to mention if you have a larger object graph (like an address, accounts etc. etc. ).

Comment: He does have a point, though! If you just want to update one column it's wasteful to fetch the object, right? To my knowledge, with hibernate you'd resort to a custom query, though.  I just recently came across this interesting article: https://blog.jooq.org/2017/03/08/many-sql-performance-problems-stem-from-unnecessary-mandatory-work/ Even though, you can argue with premature optimization, this is definitely true and can save you many bucks paying for a bigger database server in the end.

Comment: Why would updating a single column or a whole object (or relations etc) needs a bigger database? Your data volume doesn't increase so not sure how a bigger database is related to larger update statements. Generally databases (and sometimes your persistence provider) are smart enough to do all sorts of optimizations but stop doing that the moment you mess around with selective updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JPA you pass the entity and the framework figures out which properties you have changed. If you did not already know this I would suggest that you spent a little more time reading about the fundamentals of JPA. On the surface JPA looks easy and approachable, but if you don't understand the principles it is built on, you will end up spending a lot of time debugging and googling to decipher the error messages.

When an entity is [managed](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed) JPA will take a copy of the object when it was loaded, and then compare it to the version passed to `save/persist` and figure out which columns should be updated. This makes for an easy-to-use developer model, where you (often) don't have to think about the changes to your entities.

You may think, as Rob suggest, that loading a single entity to change a single property is wasteful, but this is not always the case. Both EclipseLink and Hibernate uses a shared (2nd level) cache by default, so if an entity has been loaded already, it may be loaded from memory instead of the DB, and once you have modified the entity, JPA compares two objects in memory and generates the SQL needed to modify columns.

Some times you need to optimize you JPA code (but only when you have measured which operations are slow). A classical scenario is bulk delete/update, where you don't want JPA to spend time reading/copying/managing entities which you are deleting/updating. In those cases you can use delete or update queries, instead of loading the entity and calling `EntityManager.remove()` or modifying the entity inside a transaction. However you should be aware that this bypasses EntityListeners and cascade instructions as these are only called for managed entities.